# VS Code: Is there a way to make a project that opens bash config files

Tags: visual-studio-code, bash, .profile

I want to quickly be able to launch a VS Code project that contains 3 files:
~/.bash_profile
~/.profile
~/.bashrc
as i frequently want to edit all 3 at once if I need to tweak things.
Is there a way to make a project out of the 3, and then be able to open a project file instead next time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding the files as argument in the shortcut. or to work on a copy create a simple .bat that copies the files in a new folder and open it.

Edit: add `-n` option, from the documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

```
-n or --new-window  Opens a new session of VS Code instead of restoring the previous session (default).
```

Comment: If you use the shortcut method you describe, is there a way to make it open in a new window? Otherwise I'd start to get the files opened in an existing project, which isn't exactly the behaviour I was after, but I get the point (I'm used to using code from terminal window on a mac.. Aliases would be a good approach if it would force it into a new window)